# TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified in .NET OracleClient

Tags: asp.net, oracleclient, tns

Im using a .net OracleClient in my machine for connecting to a Database in Oracle. When im trying to connect its showing this TNS Error.

Now, I have edited the tnsnames.ora file and sqlnet.ora file.
When I access the Oracle using a ServerExplorer. It gets connected to the Oracle Database and its fetching everything.

I do have a ODAC component from oracle website itself which also, i tried but dint worked.

My connection string is`<add name="netOracleClient" connectionString="Data Source=ff.WORLD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=vlc;Password=vlc;Unicode=True"
      providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=ff.WORLD;PASSWORD=vlc;USER ID=vlc"
      providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />`

I tried with ServerExplorer in both the components. Its working FINE with Server explorer and im getting the datas too.
But when i write the code its throwing me this error ORA-12154:
TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

This is the code from which Im trying to connect.

```
 OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["netOracleClient"].ConnectionString);
```

Tell me a way to resolve this???

NOTE: We have machines here itself from which we are accesing the same database with the same TNS using OracleClient for .net. I also wants to use the same..

Please Help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now Its working for me.
The steps we followed for doing this.

- We noticed we were having more than One TNSNames.ORA file.
- Then we   could find it was pointing to Oracle Client version 8.x.So it was
  not working properly.  So for working with it...
- We removed all the    ORacle Client Versions(since we were not able
  to point VisualStudio    Oracle Client to a newer version)
- Re-Installed it again. After a    Restart it started Working.

Answer (score 0):

We have ODAC working fine with this connection string,

```
<ConnectionString name="ServerConnection">Data Source=PROD;User Id=DBUSER1;Password=DBPASSWORD1;Pooling=False;</ConnectionString>
```

together with the tnsnames.ora defining the Data Source - PROD same like in the sample tnsnames.ora file in the Oracle/Network/Admin folder.

tnsnames.ora entry goes like this

```
DDSENT3 =    
  (DESCRIPTION =        
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.15.10)(PORT = 1521))    
    (CONNECT_DATA =    
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)    
      (SERVICE_NAME = DDSENT3)    
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your `web.config`:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <!-- Set this path if you are using TNS aliases as connection strings (not recommended) -->
        <!-- Instead you can use "SERVER_NAME:PORT/SERVICE_NAME" as your data source -->
        <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_3\Network\Admin\"/>
      </settings>
...
```

Just add your folder location, of course.